# XAMPP services cannot be installed or uninstalled while the service is running! Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am trying to install XAMPP but cannot get all the services to work.  I turned off the User Account Control and reopened xampp but now my SQL was running but some were not. Apache has the error [services cannot be installed or uninstalled while the service is running!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPKNY.png)

I am new to wordpress. Using windows to learn wordpress websites using a local server insead of a using wordpress online.
Would WAMP be eaiser to install and use than XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is a windows solution. so - please install WAMP, and run your local server from there.